# When moving from Blogger to WordPress do I need to remove Google Search Console and Analytics from the old Blogger site?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, blogger

I initially hosted my website using Blogger's free hosting platform. I accordingly linked Analytics and Google Search Console with the site. Recently I switched to WordPress while the domain remains unchanged. I added the Analytics and Google Search Console code using Header and Footer plugin in WordPress new website.

Is it okay? Or did I need to delete any traces of Google Search Console code and Analytics from the previous website which I used in Blogger?

Answer (score 2):

you can test if the GA works by sending a test traffic.

1. Go to admin by clicking the gear icon at the bottom
   [image]
2. Choose and Click Tracking Code

[image]

3. Click the button SEND TEST TRAFFIC

[image]

4. Go to your analytics.google.com and check the real time visits

[image]

Then on Google webmaster tools add another property[image]

You need to add version of your site to google webmaster since your previous version was blogger